# Could not find correct provider

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I'm starting to learn Flutter and I'm trying to use provider.
I've follow a few tutorials and now starting my side project but I'm stuck with these error:

`Error: Could not find the correct Provider<CultivatorModel> above this CultivatorComponent Widget`

As I wrapped the MaterialApp with the Multiproviders, it should be in the ancestor... That error does not make sense to me, I'm certainly to new to flutter and I'm missing something obvious...

Anyway, here is my code, thanks for your help.

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter_app/components/cultivator_component.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/incarnation_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/models/cultivator_model.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
      MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => IncarnationModel()),
            ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => CultivatorModel()),
          ],
          child: GameApp())
  );
}

class GameApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CultivatorComponent(),
    );
  }
}
```

**cultivator_component.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

import 'package:flutter_app/Models/cultivator_model.dart';

class CultivatorComponent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cultivatorModel = Provider.of<CultivatorModel>(context);
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('${cultivatorModel.cultivator.name} is here')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**cultivator_model**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';

import 'package:flutter_app/domain/cultivator.dart';
import 'package:flutter_app/domain/incarnation.dart';

class CultivatorModel with ChangeNotifier{
  Cultivator _cultivator;

  Cultivator get cultivator => _cultivator;

  CultivatorModel(){
    _cultivator = Cultivator("MyCultivator");
  }

  bool canCreateIncarnation() => _cultivator.canCreateIncarnation();

  void addIncarnation(Incarnation incarnation){
    _cultivator.incarnations.add(incarnation);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand your question. I'm trying to have a clean architecture, hence the separation between the Views, Models and a state management/DI with the Provider package.

Comment: For me everything is working as expected, the widget was rendered and value is displayed on the screen.

Comment: hum, that's unexpected. Are you using Android Studio? I guess you did some changes as i didn't paste some domain classes. Do you mind putting your code on a github?

Comment: I'm using IntelliJ Idea, Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable and iOS virtual device.
I can post my code here as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how my version works, I didn't do any major changes and my configuration is *IntelliJ Idea, Flutter 1.9.1+hotfix.6 • channel stable and iOS virtual device*

If you would have any problem with running the next code, please contact me and I try to help.

```
import 'dart:core';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => AnotherModel()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(builder: (context) => CultivatorModel()),
      ],
      child: GameApp())
  );
}

class GameApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: CultivatorComponent(),
    );
  }
}

class CultivatorComponent extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final cultivatorModel = Provider.of<CultivatorModel>(context);
    final anotherModel = Provider.of<AnotherModel>(context);
    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('${cultivatorModel.cultivator} is here'),
          Text('${anotherModel.modelNum} is here')
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class CultivatorModel with ChangeNotifier{
  String _cultivator;

  String get cultivator => _cultivator;

  CultivatorModel(){
    _cultivator = "MyCultivator";
  }

  void addIncarnation(String incarnation){
    _cultivator = incarnation;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}



class AnotherModel with ChangeNotifier{
  int _modelNum;

  int get modelNum => _modelNum;

  AnotherModel(){
    _modelNum = 55;
  }

  void changeNumber(int num){
    _modelNum = num;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

Comment: This is working too with me. I really don't understand why my branch is not working, it make no sense... Anyway thanks for confirming that my understanding of provider was correct, I'll reset my code to the latest working version and carry on from there. I accept your post as the correct answer.

Comment: Can you then update all code in your question? I mean, show missed classes that we could figure out what's wrong with it

Comment: I can send you my git repo and you could have a look, how can I contact you?

Comment: Let's continue here: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202471/https-stackoverflow-com-questions-58890462